# Config import conflict, how to remove lock

Tags: 8, configuration

I am trying to import config on my staging site, and I repeatedly get the following message:

> Another request may be synchronizing configuration already.

I know that there are no other processes currently importing config, so there is some rogue lock.

I am using config_split module on the site, but both methods of config import report the lock.
I have updated the site to Drupal 8.6.1 but the issue may have existed prior to the update.

Question: How can I remove the lock using Drush or some other method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My specific issue was that Redis module update to 1.0 brought with it new `redis.services.yml` file in the module. Updating my site's Redis services file, in sites/default/, resolved the issue.

What was happening was that the `alreadyImporting()` method of ConfigImporter defaults to true, when in fact my mis-configuration would have been returning an error I think.

This issue pointed me in the right direction: https://www.drupal.org/project/redis/issues/2996655

If it had been a simple lock issue the following should have worked I think:

```
drush ev "\Drupal::lock()->release('config_importer');"
```

Comment: Bummer, unfortunately, this didn't resolve my issue. Oh well, thanks for posting.

Comment: This also happens when lock is moved to Memcached.

Answer (score 0):

I had a `memcache.yml` file in `sites/default` that was switching the default lock backend with a memcache implementation. Since I did not have memcache running, I was unable to import the configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Run `drush cr`, wait for 10 seconds, and try again. The import will work.